# How to make a footer grid with css and html?

Tags: html, css

File `css`

```
/* FOOTER NAV MENU */
#footer-navmenu {
background: black;
padding: 25px 0px;
font: ubuntu;
color: red;
}
#footer-navmenu h3{
    display: inline-block;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font: normal 25px 'Quango', cursive;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px;
    border-bottom: 5px double #7FFFD4; 
}
#footer-navmenu h3 span{
    color:  #5383d3;
}
#footer-navmenu footer-links{
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
    padding: 0;
}
#footer-navmenu footer-links a{
    display:grid;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}
#footer-navmenu-container {
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
}
#footer-navmenu ul {
list-style: circle;
margin: 0;
}
#footer-navmenu ul li {
display: grid;
margin: 6px 0;
}
#footer-navmenu ul li::after {
content:"";
}
#footer-navmenu ul li:last-child::after {
content:"";
}
#footer-navmenu ul li a {
color: white;
margin: 0 15px;
}
#footer-navmenu ul li a:hover {
color: $(navmenufooter.hover.color);
border-bottom: 2px solid $(navmenufooter.hover.color);
}

/* ASSET HIJABEN */
```

File `html`

```
<!-- footer nav menu -->
<div id='footer-navmenu'>
<nav id='footer-navmenu-container'>

<!-- menu navigasi footer start -->
<h3>Hijaben<span>crew</span></h3>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="https://blog.xyz/">• HC Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www./p/radio-streaming-hijaben.html">• HC Radio</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://91/">• HC Webchat</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www./p/join-hijaben-crew.html">• Rekrutmen</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.z/p/visi-misi.html">• Visi Misi</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www/p/terms-of-use.html">• Ketentuan Pengguna</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www./p/privacy-policy.html">• Kebijakan Privasi</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www./p/donasi.html">• Donasi</a></li>
   </ul>
<!-- menu navigasi footer end -->
<p><div id='footer-navmenu'>
<h3>Thank's<span> To</span></h3>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="https://blog./">• HC Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www./p/radio-streaming-hijaben.html">• HC Radio</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://91./">• HC Webchat</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www./p/join-hijaben-crew.html">• Rekrutmen</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www./p/visi-misi.html">• Visi Misi</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.website.tld/p/terms-of-use.html">• Ketentuan Pengguna</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.website.tld/p/privacy-policy.html">• Kebijakan Privasi</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.website">• Donasi</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   </p>
</nav>
</div>
<!-- footer nav menu end -->
```

this is the result [Codepen.io results](https://codepen.io/hijaben/pen/oNNNLbx)

I want to make it like this [Footer Bottom](https://filebin.net/21ejtf0rfqsd8qby/IMG_20191005_130203.jpg)

Can the experts help me solve this? be like that picture!
footer bottom which flattens into several plots in one container that is sideways or horizontal, mine only has to be from top to bottom or vertical

Comment: what's your problem exactly??  you want to create a horizontal footer??

Comment: just a correction, CSS is not a programming language by the way.

Comment: Saya ingin menampilkan menu nav footer saya secara horizontal dengan menggunakan CSS, masalahnya adalah saya tidak terlalu mahir dengan kode CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be the image that you sent to me is nothing aligned to anything, not even the titles. And there is a lot of problems with your code. For example, you cant declare an ID with the same name on the same page. Another problem is that I found a

lost in the middle of the code to nest another divs.this is incorrect. And finally, don't use a lot of nested divs inside divs. It only makes your code more confused and they aren't doing anything. this is the solution:

[

```css
/* FOOTER NAV MENU */
#footer-navmenu {
width:100%;
background: black;
padding: 25px 0px;
font: ubuntu;
color: red;

}

.parent-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:center;
  alig-content:center;
}

.container-child{
  margin: 0 6rem;
}

#footer-navmenu h3{
    display:inline-block;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font: normal 25px 'Quango', cursive;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px;
    border-bottom: 5px double #7FFFD4;
}



#footer-navmenu h3 span{
    color:  #5383d3;
}

#footer-navmenu footer-links a{
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}

#footer-navmenu ul {
color:white;
list-style: circle;
margin: 0;
}

#footer-navmenu ul li a {
color: white;

}
```

```html
<!-- footer nav menu -->
<div id='footer-navmenu'>
<nav class="parent-container" id='footer-navmenu-container'>

  <!-- BLOCK 1 -->
  <div class="container-child">
  <h3>Hijaben<span>crew</span></h3>
     <ul>
          <li><a href="https://blog.xyz/">• HC Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www./p/radio-streaming-hijaben.html">• HC Radio</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://91/">• HC Webchat</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www./p/join-hijaben-crew.html">• Rekrutmen</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.z/p/visi-misi.html">• Visi Misi</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www/p/terms-of-use.html">• Ketentuan Pengguna</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www./p/privacy-policy.html">• Kebijakan Privasi</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www./p/donasi.html">• Donasi</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- BLOCK 2-->
  
  <div class="container-child">
  <h3>Thank's<span> To</span></h3>
     <ul>
          <li><a href="https://blog./">• HC Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www./p/radio-streaming-hijaben.html">• HC Radio</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://91./">• HC Webchat</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www./p/join-hijaben-crew.html">• Rekrutmen</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www./p/visi-misi.html">• Visi Misi</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.website.tld/p/terms-of-use.html">• Ketentuan Pengguna</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.website.tld/p/privacy-policy.html">• Kebijakan Privasi</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://www.website">• Donasi</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  
</nav>
</div>
<!-- footer nav menu end -->
```

][1](https://codepen.io/raquelsartwork/pen/RwwwywM?editors=1100)

Comment: feel free to add my solution by clicking on the check on my answer. hope i was helpfull. have a nice day coding

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this that you are after using `display: inline-block;`

```css
/* FOOTER NAV MENU */

#footer-navmenu {
  background: black;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  font: $(navmenufooter.font);
  color: $(navmenufooter.color);
}

#footer-navmenu h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font: normal 25px 'Quango', cursive;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px;
  border-bottom: 5px double #7FFFD4;
}

#footer-navmenu h3 span {
  color: #5383d3;
}

#footer-navmenu footer-links {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 20px 0 12px;
  padding: 0;
}

#footer-navmenu footer-links a {
  display: grid;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#footer-navmenu-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}

#footer-navmenu ul {
  list-style: circle;
  margin: 0;
}

#footer-navmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 6px 0;
}

#footer-navmenu ul li::after {
  content: "";
}

#footer-navmenu ul li:last-child::after {
  content: "";
}

#footer-navmenu ul li a {
  color: $(navmenufooter.color);
  margin: 0 15px;
}

#footer-navmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: $(navmenufooter.hover.color);
  border-bottom: 2px solid $(navmenufooter.hover.color);
}


/* ASSET HIJABEN */
```

```html
<!-- footer nav menu -->
<div id='footer-navmenu'>
  <nav id='footer-navmenu-container'>

    <!-- menu navigasi footer start -->
    <h3>Hijaben<span>crew</span></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://blog.xyz/">• HC Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www./p/radio-streaming-hijaben.html">• HC Radio</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://91/">• HC Webchat</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www./p/join-hijaben-crew.html">• Rekrutmen</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.z/p/visi-misi.html">• Visi Misi</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www/p/terms-of-use.html">• Ketentuan Pengguna</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www./p/privacy-policy.html">• Kebijakan Privasi</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www./p/donasi.html">• Donasi</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- menu navigasi footer end -->
    <div id='footer-navmenu'>
      <h3>Thank's<span> To</span></h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://blog./">• HC Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www./p/radio-streaming-hijaben.html">• HC Radio</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://91./">• HC Webchat</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www./p/join-hijaben-crew.html">• Rekrutmen</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www./p/visi-misi.html">• Visi Misi</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.website.tld/p/terms-of-use.html">• Ketentuan Pengguna</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.website.tld/p/privacy-policy.html">• Kebijakan Privasi</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.website">• Donasi</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>
</div>
<!-- footer nav menu end -->
```

And if you need the links to align correctly, you can use `display:grid;`

```css
/* FOOTER NAV MENU */

#footer-navmenu {
  background: black;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  font: $(navmenufooter.font);
  color: $(navmenufooter.color);
}

#footer-navmenu h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font: normal 25px 'Quango', cursive;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 5px;
  border-bottom: 5px double #7FFFD4;
}

#footer-navmenu h3 span {
  color: #5383d3;
}

#footer-navmenu footer-links {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 20px 0 12px;
  padding: 0;
}

#footer-navmenu footer-links a {
  display: grid;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#footer-navmenu-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
}

#footer-navmenu ul {
  list-style: circle;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

#footer-navmenu ul li {
  margin: 6px 0;
}

#footer-navmenu ul li::after {
  content: "";
}

#footer-navmenu ul li:last-child::after {
  content: "";
}

#footer-navmenu ul li a {
  color: $(navmenufooter.color);
}

#footer-navmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: $(navmenufooter.hover.color);
  border-bottom: 2px solid $(navmenufooter.hover.color);
}


/* ASSET HIJABEN */
```

```html
<!-- footer nav menu -->
<div id='footer-navmenu'>
  <nav id='footer-navmenu-container'>

    <!-- menu navigasi footer start -->
    <h3>Hijaben<span>crew</span></h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://blog.xyz/">• HC Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www./p/radio-streaming-hijaben.html">• HC Radio</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://91/">• HC Webchat</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www./p/join-hijaben-crew.html">• Rekrutmen</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.z/p/visi-misi.html">• Visi Misi</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www/p/terms-of-use.html">• Ketentuan Pengguna</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www./p/privacy-policy.html">• Kebijakan Privasi</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www./p/donasi.html">• Donasi</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- menu navigasi footer end -->
    <div id='footer-navmenu'>
      <h3>Thank's<span> To</span></h3>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://blog./">• HC Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www./p/radio-streaming-hijaben.html">• HC Radio</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://91./">• HC Webchat</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www./p/join-hijaben-crew.html">• Rekrutmen</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www./p/visi-misi.html">• Visi Misi</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.website.tld/p/terms-of-use.html">• Ketentuan Pengguna</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.website.tld/p/privacy-policy.html">• Kebijakan Privasi</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.website">• Donasi</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </nav>
</div>
<!-- footer nav menu end -->
```

Comment: This hm `display: inline-block;` for `<h3>` if the others already display grids, if the grid display is applied for `<h3>` it's going to fall apart

Comment: yep, `h3` does not require `inline-block`. I just fixed the footer for you, but i think this code can get more cleaner. do you want me to fix that as well?

Comment: I have found the problem, and now it is what I want it to be. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to align your `<ul>` in the left side, remember that
>   `<ul>` has some extra margin and padding in the left side.

So to fix this problems simply you need to remove padding and margin in the left side by doing this:

```
padding-left: 0;
margin-left: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want.
Do you want to align horizontally the groups of lists? (each ul)

If is that you are looking for you just need to put this :

```
add CSS in the element parent that is <nav id='footer-navmenu-container'>

#footer-navmenu-container{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start; // if you want to align your items in the left. if not 
                              erase this line  of code
}
```

Comment: I have tried but, the results of the title with the first line menu are not aligned

Comment: this is what I want, friend [link](https://pasteboard.co/IACAeZ9.jpg) making each menu in the container line up horizontally

Comment: it seems to be the image that you sent to me is nothing aligned to anything, not even the titles. And there is a lot of problems with your code. For example, you cant declare an ID with the same name on the same page. Another problem is that I found a <p> lost in the middle of the code to nest another divs.this is incorrect. And finally, don't use a lot of nested divs inside divs. It only makes your code more confused and they aren't doing anything.  this is the solution: [link] (https://codepen.io/raquelsartwork/pen/RwwwywM?editors=1100) copy and tell me when you don't need more to erase